# bit.ly redirect method

Tags: php, header, bit.ly

Any ideas if bit.ly is doing anything other than simple `Location:` header to redirect users?

Facebook is able to parse info about final destination when using `bit.ly` link, but not my project `http://guubo.com/aaaaab` links that use simple `Location:` header.

I checked bit.ly headers, they look ordinary.

Comment: I suspect that they do a fetch (e.g. using `curl`) and then inspect the headers.

Comment: make sure you have no html tags.

Comment: I suspect FB is calling the bit.ly API, because it's popular enough to have warranted the effort required: [link](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/v3/expand)

Comment: Facebook/Bit.ly? Facebook obviously does that, yes and that is the issue: while it works with bit.ly links, it doesn't with guubo.com. I wonder what they are doing different. Bit.ly does not do that, they return empty body.

Comment: @zzlawlzz no content is returned at all. @xs0 what about it?

Comment: Looks like a normal redirect to me; see my answer below.

Comment: Facebook probably knows bit.ly is a short URL service and follows the *Location* redirection automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked into it further.  Try the following from the command line

```
curl -D headers.txt http://bit.ly/4m1AUx
```

You can then look at the contents of `headers.txt`, which will look like

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 28 May 2011 13:18:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: _bit=4de0f61d-001f7-008b9-d8ac8fa8;domain=.bit.ly;expires=Thu Nov 24 08:18:21 2011;path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-control: private; max-age=90
Location: http://slashdot.org/
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Length: 112
```

So, no, they're doing a normal 301 redirect.  You can do the same inspection in your PHP code using [PHP's curl bindings](https://www.php.net/curl) to get the headers to figure out the real site if you want.

Comment: `header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved'); header('Location: ' . $url);` when link is shared on Facebook.com it still shares guubo.com's details rather than the `$url`'s.

Comment: So, the answer is that *Facebook* is doing something different, not bit.ly.  Which is unfortunate from your perspective, if you're trying to write a URL shortener, as it may not be possible to work around.

Comment: FWIW, you could also use `curl -I` or `curl -D -` to print the response headers to stdout instead of saving them to a file.

Comment: Yeah, I have an alias set up to dump them these days - `alias headers='curl -s -D - -o /dev/null'`, then just call `headers somesite.com`.

Answer (score 0):

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41680608/7426396

I implemented to get a each line of a plain text file, with one shortened url per line, the according redirect url:

```
<?php
// input: textfile with one bitly shortened url per line
$plain_urls = file_get_contents('in.txt');
$bitly_urls = explode("\r\n", $plain_urls);

// output: where should we write
$w_out = fopen("out.csv", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");

foreach($bitly_urls as $bitly_url) {
  $c = curl_init($bitly_url);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36');
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
  // curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'localhost:9150');
  // curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
  $r = curl_exec($c);

  // get the redirect url:
  $redirect_url = curl_getinfo($c)['redirect_url'];

  // write output as csv
  $out = '"'.$bitly_url.'";"'.$redirect_url.'"'."\n";
  fwrite($w_out, $out);
}
fclose($w_out);
```

Have fun and enjoy!
pw